# setAttribute for animation component 'to' attribute using position fails to set

Tags: javascript, aframe

I'm using A-Frame (webVR) to make a multi panorama explorer. The world has a few 3d buttons (with panorama mapped spheres at each button position). You click on a button, and an animation component moves the camera from its current location to the button location. A custom component containing a listener (for click events on buttons), uses setAttribute to set the 'to' and 'from' attributes of an animation component on the camera. An emit command triggers the animation. Unfortunately it fails, and I can see that the 'from' attribute is not setting correctly (it is setting to the same as 'to'). It doesn't throw errors, but I can see in the console that the from will not set,even though I set it explicitly.

I've already got this working in a previous version. You can see and test it here:
https://glitch.com/~camera-jumper

In this version, I don't set the from attribute, and it still works fine, presumably because it takes the previous value as a default.

Then I built in some other functionality and now it is failing. You can see the current version here:
https://glitch.com/~panojumper

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('buttoncontrol', { 
    schema: {
        pano:{type:'string',default: 'pSphere1'} 
    },  
    init: function(){   
        var el = this.el;       
        var cam = document.querySelector('#camera'); 
        var panoManEntity = document.querySelector('#panoMan'); 
        var panoName = this.data.pano;
        console.log(cam.getAttribute('animation__jump', 'to'));
        this.el.addEventListener('click', function(evt){

            // Animate the camera moving to the button position
            var btnpos = el.getAttribute('position'); 
            var cam = document.querySelector('#camera');
            var campos = cam.getAttribute('position');              

            cam.setAttribute('animation__jump','to', {x: btnpos.x, y: 
              btnpos.y, z: btnpos.z });             
            cam.setAttribute('animation__jump','from', {x: campos.x, y: 
              campos.y, z: campos.z });     
            cam.emit('camjump');
        }); 
    }
});
```

I expect setAttribute for 'from' to be what I am setting it to, but it is the same as the 'to' value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `from` attribute seems to be working, you can verify it by modifying your first glitch. Add the `from` attribute, and its still working properly:

```
var campos = cam.getAttribute('position')
// Animate the camera moving to the button position
cam.setAttribute('animation__jump','to', {x: btnpos.x, y: btnpos.y, z: btnpos.z });
cam.setAttribute('animation__jump','from', {x: campos.x, y: campos.y, z: campos.z });
```

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/ykzp2m6a/3/).

---

The other glitch will also work if you register the custom components in the `<head>` or at least before the `<a-scene>`. There is also a note on it in the [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html#sidebar).

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/kpzm5w14/3/).

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much. That fixed it and makes perfect sense. I'm still a noon at Aframe.

Comment: Glad its helpful :) if you don't have further questions feel free to mark the anwser :)

Answer (score 0):

You nailed it! Custom components must not be in the scene, but in the head. I moved it because my assets tag was before the scene tag, which threw an error, so I moved the scene tag too far north. Moving the scene tag below registerComponents solved it. 
All of this is in the docs, but I'm a noob. Thanks for your help!